# grep two words near each other

Tags: regex, grep

Say I have a line in a file "This is perhaps the easiest place to add new functionality." and I want to grep two words close to each other. I do

```
grep -ERHn "\beasiest\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,6}?place\b" *
```

that works and gives me the line. But when I do

```
grep -ERHn "\beasiest\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,10}?new\b" *
```

it fails, defeating the whole point of the *{1,10}?*
This one is listed in the regular-expression.info site and also a couple of Regex books. Though they do not describe it with grep but that should not matter.

**Update**

I put the regex into a python script. Works, but doesn't have the nice grep -C thing ...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
import sys
import os

word1 = sys.argv[1]
word2 = sys.argv[2]
dist = sys.argv[3]
regex_string = (r'\b(?:' 
    + word1  
    + r'\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,'
    + dist
    + '}?'
    + word2 
    + r'|'
    + word2
    + r'\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,'
            + dist
    + '}?'
    + word1
    + r')\b')

regex = re.compile(regex_string)


def findmatches(PATH):
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(PATH):
    for filename in files:
        fullpath = os.path.join(root,filename)

        with open(fullpath, 'r') as f:
            matches = re.findall(regex, f.read())
            for m in matches:
                print "File:",fullpath,"\n\t",m

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    findmatches(sys.argv[4])
```

Calling it as

```
python near.py charlie winning 6 path/to/charlie/sheen
```

works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need the look ahead structure?
Maybe this is enough:

```
grep -ERHn "\beasiest\W+(\w+\W+){1,10}new\b" *
```

Here is what I get:

```
echo "This is perhaps the easiest place to add new functionality." | grep -EHn "\beasiest\W+(\w+\W+){1,10}new\b"
```

> (standard input):1:This is perhaps the easiest place to add new
>   functionality.

**Edit**

As Camille Goudeseune said:

To make it easily usable, this can be added in a .bashrc:

```
grepNear() {
 grep -EHn "\b$1\W+(\w+\W+){1,10}$2\b"
}.
```

Then at a bash prompt: `echo "..." | grepNear easiest new`

Comment: For convenience, put this in your `.bashrc`: `grepNear() { grep -EHn "\b$1\W+(\w+\W+){1,10}$2\b" ; }`.  Then at a bash prompt: `echo "..." | grepNear easiest new`.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` does not support the non-capturing groups of Python regular expressions. When you write something like `(?:\w+\W+)`, you are asking `grep` to match a question mark `?` followed by a colon `:` followed by one or more word chars `\w+` followed by one or more non-word chars `\W+`. `?` is a special character for `grep` regexes, for sure, but since it is following the beginning of a group, it is automatically escaped (in the same way that the regex `[?]` matches the question mark).

Let us test it? I have the following file:

```
$ cat file
This is perhaps the easiest place to add new functionality.
```

`grep` does not match it with the expression you used:

```
$ grep -ERHn "\beasiest\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,10}?new\b" file
```

Then, I created the following file:

```
$ cat file2
This is perhaps the easiest ?:place ?:to ?:add new functionality.
```

Note that each word is preceded by `?:`.  In this case, your expression matches the file:

```
$ grep -ERHn "\beasiest\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,10}?new\b" file2
file2:1:This is perhaps the easiest ?:place ?:to ?:add new functionality.
```

The solution is to remove the `?:` of the expression:

```
$ grep -ERHn "\beasiest\W+(\w+\W+){1,10}?new\b" file
file:1:This is perhaps the easiest place to add new functionality.
```

Since you do not even need a non-capturing group (at least as far as I've seen) it does not bear any problem.

*Bonus point*: you can simplify your expression changing `{1,10}` to `{0,10}` and removing the following `?`:

```
$ grep -ERHn "\beasiest\W+(\w+\W+){0,10}new\b" file
file:1:This is perhaps the easiest place to add new functionality.
```

Answer (score 0):

E.g.
**find "select .......from" in php files**

```
grep --include \*.php -REHn "\bselect\W+(\w+\W+){1,10}from\b" *
```